# Wrong version of PHP is used when called from a script

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, redhat

I apologize ahead of time if this question is really basic. My background is in Windows and I am being asked to maintain a RedHat Linux server that is in bad shape and is in production use.

The issue is that the version of PHP is different when executed from a script in Apache vs. the command line.

For example:

From the command line:

[image]

From the web page  (Apache):

[image]

From the a php script called by a web page:

[image]

The script is called by this php code and function:

```
$exec_result = sku_exec(CLIMPORT.FILE_NAV, '', $_POST['nav_skus']);

function sku_exec($file_path, $call, $args)
{
    $exe = $file_path.' ';
    if($call != '' && isset($call) && $call) $exe .= $call.' ';
    $exe .= $args;
//  echo $exe.'<hr />';
    exec('php '.$exe, $return_data);
    return $return_data;
}
```

I need to downgrade the script to use 5.2.9 instead of 5.4.1.

Where do I even start to look for how this is configured? Why would the version of PHP that Apache is using be different from the version that it is calling from a script?

I looked at Apache’s config file but did not see anything that jumped out at me.

Any suggestions?

Unfortunately, upgrading the server to the latest PHP is not an option at the moment. The plan is to build out a new server and migrate to it.

Comment: Show us the code from the web page that's calling the php script(!?!).

Comment: I am beginning to think that this has to do with the account that Apache is running under vs. the account I use for testing

Comment: So it'll be a path or binary naming issue (you didn't indicate what command you ran to get the version information in your initial question).  Since you've got no Linux skills, you might have an uphill battle tracking this one down, but at the very least run `find / -name php` to see what different PHP binaries there are on the system.  And if you know who wrote that bit of code, do us all a favour and beat them with a stick until they agree to change careers to flower arranging or something.

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated to your question, but the code snippet you've posted contains a classic [Command Line Injection vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). You're taking user input directly from a web-based form via the $_POST['nav_skus'] variable, and then you're calling exec('php '.$exe, $return_data) (which contains the value of the $_POST input) later on without actually sanitizing the data first.

Comment: @womble I used find and was able to locate more than ten php binaries. What a mess. The engineer responsible for this mess has long since changed careers.

Comment: @kmit This website is an internal tool. The html code does some scrubbing and the data is checked against a list of valid skus so I am not too worried. Thanks!

Comment: @rboarman Client-side scrubbing is ineffective. One can always craft an HTTP POST manually or simply intercept the form post en-route with a Browser Plugin and modify the desired fields. Additionally, even if it is internal, an attacker could use this to potentially root your server if they gain access to your LAN (i.e. privilege escalation). Finally, who said all the bad guys are on the outside? Every company has disgruntled employees. The solution is to scrub the data properly on the server-side. Consider a PHP library like Flourish lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `which php` from CLI and add the path to the script so that you are running `exec('/path/to/the/cli/php`. Should your user be so restricted to not be able to run which (that'd be seriously messed up): the user running the command line has a different environment and so a different `PATH` to what the user has. The `PATH` variable, if I remember correctly although it was long ago, exists even in DOS. So take the values in PATH (`echo $PATH`) and manually check which dir contains a file called `php`. That's what `which` does, anyways.

You badly need to read some basic Linux book if this is now your job.

Comment: My job is really to keep the thing alive until I can migrate a copy to a new environment. I plan on hiring someone to help.

Comment: The root account has been disabled but I can run sudo bash which seems to be good enough so far.

Comment: I changed the exec('php'... code to exec('php5'...) and it seems to have worked. Any downsides to this change?

Comment: @rboarman: That would seem like the least-worst option to fix the immediate problem, under the circumstances.